# UIPageViewController using without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have an api as below:-

```
{
"datashow": [
{
  "name": "seena",
  "age": 34,
  "city": "u.k",
  "type": "human"
},
{
  "name": "cat",
  "age": 3,
  "city": "u.s.a",
  "type": "animal"
},
{
  "name": "parrot",
  "age": 31,
  "city": "south africa",
  "type": "bird"
}
],
  "link": {}
}
```

This is an example So, i need to get the count of "datashow" only.So here the count is 3.So ,now i need to create `UIPageViewController` for this.

That means i need 3 screens with pagecontrol.In that first screen it should display the details as seena, 34, u.k in label. Then in 2nd screen it should display as cat,3,u.s.a and also 3rd screen same pattern.

How to do this ? It must not using storyboard to display the screen it can use `xib` for `UIViewController`. How to do in swift?

Comment: you could do it programatically :)

Comment: @how to do in xib

Comment: @MahendraGP i have updated my question .please check and how to solve this problem

Comment: @ChristeenaJoseph - Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is far too broad. You need to take it step-by-step. First, learn how to instantiate and use a view / viewController from a XIB. Second, learn how to programmatically create and use a `UIPageViewController`. Third, combine what you've learned from steps 1 and 2. If you run into *specific problems*, come back and ask *specific questions*.

Answer (score 0):

here is all ViewController code

```
import UIKit
```

extension UIColor {
static func random() -> UIColor {
return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),green: .random(in: 0...1),blue:  .random(in: 0...1),alpha: 1.0
)
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate   {

```
@IBOutlet weak var topTabCollectionView:UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var pagesContainerView:UIView!

private var pageController: UIPageViewController!
private var arrVC:[UIViewController] = []
private var currentPage: Int!

var numberOfTabArr = ["All","Movie","Songs","TV Serials","WebSeriese","News","Romantic","Recent Uploaded",]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    supposeYourTabDataGetHere()
    currentPage = 0
    createPageViewController()
    
    topTabCollectionView.dataSource = self
    topTabCollectionView.delegate = self
    
}

func supposeYourTabDataGetHere(){
    
    for name in numberOfTabArr {
        let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListControllerVC") as! ListControllerVC
        vc1.tabName = name
        vc1.TabId = "someID"
        vc1.color = UIColor.random()
        arrVC.append(vc1)
    }
    
}

private func createPageViewController() {
    
    pageController = UIPageViewController.init(transitionStyle: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)
    
    pageController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    pageController.delegate = self
    pageController.dataSource = self
    
    for svScroll in pageController.view.subviews as! [UIScrollView] {
        svScroll.delegate = self
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.pageController.view.frame = self.pagesContainerView.bounds
        
    }
    pageController.setViewControllers([arrVC[0]], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    
    self.addChild(pageController)
    self.pagesContainerView.addSubview(pageController.view)
    pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
}

private func indexofviewController(viewCOntroller: UIViewController) -> Int {
    if(arrVC .contains(viewCOntroller)) {
        return arrVC.firstIndex(of: viewCOntroller)!
    }
    return -1
}




//MARK: - Pagination Delegate Methods

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = indexofviewController(viewCOntroller: viewController)
    if(index != -1) {
        index = index - 1
    }
    if(index < 0) {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        return arrVC[index]
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = indexofviewController(viewCOntroller: viewController)
    if(index != -1) {
        index = index + 1
    }
    if(index >= arrVC.count) {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        return arrVC[index]
    }
}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    
    if(completed) {
        currentPage = arrVC.firstIndex(of: (pageViewController.viewControllers?.last)!)
        topTabCollectionView.reloadData()
        let indexpath = IndexPath(row: currentPage, section: 0)
        topTabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexpath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

}

//FOR TAB
extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return numberOfTabArr.count
}

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    
    let lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(11) as? UILabel
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    
    lbl?.text = numberOfTabArr[indexPath.row]
    
    if indexPath.row == currentPage {
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    label.text = numberOfTabArr[indexPath.row]
    label.sizeToFit()
    return CGSize(width: label.frame.size.width+15, height: 32)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if currentPage>indexPath.row{
        pageController.setViewControllers([arrVC[indexPath.row]], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        currentPage = indexPath.row
        topTabCollectionView.reloadData()
        
        topTabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
    else if currentPage<indexPath.row{
        pageController.setViewControllers([arrVC[indexPath.row]], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        currentPage =  indexPath.row
        topTabCollectionView.reloadData()
        
        topTabCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }else{
        //already at same index
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you want to use xib, not storyboard. Storyboard will give you more power over xib.

But, this must be helpful for you
https://github.com/Satish/OnboardingPageViewController/

Comment: It's not a good idea to post links as answers - often the link disappears / becomes invalid over time. This should either be a comment, or you should post the pertinent information that can be found at that link (so your answer would have value, even if the page at the link is removed). see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer